# PHP multiple files upload

Tags: php, file, upload

Yes, I know that there are hundreds of questions similar, but I didn't find a working answer...
The problem is: I want upload multiple files...
The correct way should be this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="?u=1">
 <input  type="file" name="myFile[]" />
 <input  type="file" name="myFile[]" />
 <input  type="file" name="myFile[]" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload!" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?
if ($_GET['u']){
foreach ($_FILES["myFile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
 if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   $tmp_name = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
   $name = $_FILES["myFile"]["name"][$key];
   // here we move it to a directory called data
   // you can move it wherever you want
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/data/$name");
 } else {
   // an error occurred, handle it here
 }
}
}

if (!$_FILES){
    echo 'WTF?? No files sent?? There\'s a problem! Let\' hope that stack overflow will solve it!';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: myFile in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\prova.php on line 18

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\prova.php on line 18
```

No files sent?? There's a problem!  How can I access files uploaded from an array input tag?

Comment: Does the echo statement fire at the bottom?

Comment: Running this locally on my mac with MAMP works fine, file is uploaded with no hitch. Could be your setup rather than the code

Comment: It works fine? I'm the only one who it doens't work?
The echo statement print the sentence, but someone modiefied my question!

Answer (score 0):

I think using `$_POST`OR `$_FILES` instead of `$_GET['u']` to verify from submission, would fix the problem...

Also you can use `<input  type="file" name="myFile[]" multiple />` once instead of so many `<input type="file">` for multiple file selection.

**NOTE :** Check php.ini for the following settings: (Edit as your needs , save & restart server)

1. file_uploads = On
2. upload_max_filesize = 2M (its 2 MB file limit by default !!! Exact error occurs as your's if file size > 2MB)
3. post_max_size = 8M (8 MB limit for post variable by default. Change as per your requirement...)
4. upload_tmp_dir = "c:/tmp" (Provide read/write permission to temporary opload directory )

This works ok in my wamp server with the above changes & settings... Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way to upload your files is to act as if you had only one, and repeat the process for every other file you have, all you have to do is give an name to your input. I would recommend using a multiple file input :

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
```

Then, you can handle the upload with a simple for :

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
            {
//set upload directory
                $target_dir = "uploads/";
                $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
                {
                    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
                    {
                        $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$target_dir.'/'.$form['name']->getData()."/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
                        {
                            $messages[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' Failed';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can use either copy or move_uploaded_file to move the file to your directory.

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code, and found that changing the line:
`move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/data/$name");` to
`move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");`
[Changing absolute path to relative path]
does the trick. Now it works fine, in my local server. That should solve it for you.

**Courtesy**:http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/788971

Comment: Do you have a folder named `data` within the folder that contains the php file. Also `data` should have write permissions. Please ensure that as well.

Comment: To ensure that the problem is not with the destination directory, try replacing the relevant line with `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);` and see if it works. If it works the uploaded file should be found within your `C:\xampp\htdocs\php` folder. In Windows the directory seperator is `\\` and in Linux it is '/' that might be causing the problem. But this check can help you make sure that this is not the problem in your case.

Comment: I tried but it did't work! I have windows...
The problem is that the variable $_FILES is undefined...
I'd like to see this:
if ($_FILES)
echo 'It works!';   working

Comment: Could you post your `php.ini` file somewhere and share us the link. I would like to check the file upload related configurations.